# JDBC Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to run the below code and getting the below error but I can't seem to see the obvious?(if it is indeed.)

Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from staff where lName='Doe' and fName='John'' at line 1

This is my code generating the error:

```
                // DELETE the employee
        System.out.println("\nDELETING THE EMPLOYEE: John Doe\n");

        int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(
                "delete from staff "+
                "where lName='Doe' and fName ='John'");
```

I'm not sure why I am getting a syntax error there because the same syntax works fine in another class where I have this:

```
            // Update the Staff member
        System.out.println("\nEXECUTING THE UPDATE FOR: John Doe\n");

        int rowsAffected = myStmt.executeUpdate(
                "update staff "+
                "set position='CEO', salary=75550 " +
                "where lName='Doe' and fName ='John'");
```

I am clearing missing something obvious at this point but I can't see it. MySQL version is 5.7.

Edit:
It does Delete in the database when i check the actual table.

Comment: A `delete` is not an update. Try `myStmt.execute`.

Comment: I forgot to add - It does Delete in the database when i check the actual table.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think I can use `myStmt.execute` as Eclipe then throws this error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int`

Comment: Don't assign the return value to an int then?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - nothing wrong with executeUpdate. Documentation here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is perfectly fine to execute a `delete` using `executeUpdate` (as documented: _"Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement. "_)